# Incorporating an integrated PowerShell terminal like Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, terminal, visual-studio-code, electron, desktop-application

I am trying to play around with Electron and create an app that will run various powershell commands. The problem is I want a live output and cannot seem to find anywhere how to implement such a feature. However I do know that visual studio code does exactly this, its an app built on Electron, and has an integrated powershell terminal with live output.

My question is does anyone have any idea how vs code actually does this? And how can I replicate this feature in my own application?

Comment: You can view the VSCode source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode), that should help you get started.

Comment: I realize that, it's much more complex and beyond my understanding when I tried to dig through it. That's why I'm reaching out to the community for help on the topic.

Comment: Perhaps https://atom.io/packages/script-runner can help.

Comment: I mean, you could look at `PowerShell_ISE.exe` with ILSpy, too.

Comment: @CameronBelt Looks like the paid book [Windows PowerShell for Developers](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/windows-powershell-for/9781449322694/ch05.html) has a chapter on embedding a PowerShell console into an application. That could help you get started.